# Redux Slice is returning an error after adding a function into a property of initial states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I've got a Redux Slice and I want to define a property with its own brother property. In this case, I want to define a `playableFields` property with `width` and `height` properties. But when I write this function, reducers comes with the problems. I am using Typescript, so maybe you should consider it.

Redux Slice file:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const levelSlice = createSlice({
  name: "level",
  initialState: {
    ... //other states
    gridSizeAndPlayableFields: {
      width: 8,
      height: 9,
      playableFields: function() { // <---- problems comes after adding this function
        return (
          {
            rows: 
              [...Array(this.height)].map(()=>
                (
                  {
                    cells: 
                      [...Array(this.width)].map(()=>
                        (
                          {status: true}
                        )
                      )
                  }
                )
              )
          }
        )
      }
    }
  reducers: {
    ... //other reducers
    changeGridSize: (state, action) => {
      state.gridSizeAndPlayableFields.width = action.payload.width,
      state.gridSizeAndPlayableFields.height = action.payload.height
    },
    changePlayableFields: (state, action) => {

      const i = action.payload.i
      const k = action.payload.k
  
      const localTable = {...state.gridSizeAndPlayableFields.playableFields}

      localTable.rows[i].cells[k].status = !localTable.rows[i].cells[k].status

      state.gridSizeAndPlayableFields.playableFields = localTable
    }
  }
})
```

[image]

[image]

If you curious what this slice does, here I'm leaving the image from that. It's defining a level's playable fields. When you click on a box, it turns false or true depending on the stuation. And the sliders above are defining that boxes' sizes...
[image]

Here is CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-framework-nkbfnd?file=/src/redux/levelSlice.tsx

Comment: can you create a sandbox using https://codesandbox.io/ please

Comment: You define `state.gridSizeAndPlayableFields.playableFields` as a function in your initial state, but then you attempt to use it as a variable later.  Choose one.

Comment: @Anis I added CodeSandbox link. Please check it.

Comment: @possum What do you mean? If I define propert as a function, then I can't change it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by changing all data in the component using states and send them to slide.

Comment: Then it was worked, but when refreshed the page it is not working anymore... I'm getting an error like: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'status' of object '#<Object>'"