# Redux Toolkit state object is not changing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'property-name' of object '#<Object>'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I want to change the data of a state object but Redux Toolkit is not changing and gives an error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'status' of object '#<Object>'`.

These lines from component:

```
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(8)
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(9)
  const [table, setTable] = useState({
    rows: 
    [...Array(height)].map(()=>
      (
        {
          cells: 
            [...Array(width)].map(()=>
              (
                {status: true}
              )
            )
        }
      )
    )
  })

  useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(changePlayableFields(table)) // <- it's not changing the state
  },[table])

  function changeCell(i:number,k:number){
    const localTable = {...table}
    localTable.rows[i].cells[k].status = !localTable.rows[i].cells[k].status // <-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'status' of object '#<Object>'
    setTable(localTable)
  }
```

changeCell function is working very well and I see the truth results on the page. But when adding useEffect codes to move new datas to keep them in memory with redux, then I get the errors.

And these are from Redux Slice:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const levelSlice = createSlice({
  name: "level",
  initialState: {
    gridSizeAndPlayableFields: {
      width: 8,
      height: 9,
      playableFields: {
        rows: 
        [...Array(9)].map(()=>
          (
            {
              cells: 
                [...Array(8)].map(()=>
                  (
                    {status: true}
                  )
                )
            }
          )
        )
      }
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    changePlayableFields: (state, action) => {
      state.gridSizeAndPlayableFields.playableFields = action.payload // <- it's not changing the data
    },
  }
})

export const {changeGridSize, changePlayableFields} = levelSlice.actions
export default levelSlice.reducer
```

It's little about my previous question, maybe you'd like to check it. Here is my previous question link: [Redux Slice is returning an error after adding a function into a property of initial states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74192849/redux-slice-is-returning-an-error-after-adding-a-function-into-a-property-of-ini)

I hope anyone can help. Thanks...

Comment: Reducers should return the new state instead of modifying existing ones, no? [Rules of Reducers](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#rules-of-reducers)

Comment: @caTS It's a slice actually... I'm changing all other states like this also.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Reducer does not update issue:**

It seems you are sending `rows` as payload of the dispatch. So you should update `gridSizeAndPlayableFields.playableFields.rows` in the reducer:

```js
    changePlayableFields: (state, action) => {
      // console.log(action.payload);
      state.gridSizeAndPlayableFields.playableFields.rows = action.payload.rows;
      // console.log(current(state.gridSizeAndPlayableFields.playableFields));
    },
```

**2. object update issue in `changeCell` method:**

In a normal function you cannot mutate the object like in `changeCell` function. You can only do this in the redux toolkit slice thanks to [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/).

You can `map` the `rows` and `cells` arrays to update the corresponding indeces' `status` values. You can write the `changeCell` method in the following way:

```js
  function changeCell(i, k) {
    if (!table) return;
    const localTable = {};
    const localTableRows = [...table.rows];
    // map rows array
    const updatedRows = localTableRows.map((item, index) => {
      // if index equals i, map its cells as well
      //... and find kth cell and change its status
      if (index === i) {
        return {
          ...item,
          cells: item.cells.map((c, idx) => {
            if (idx === k) {
              return {
                ...c,
                status: !c.status,
              };
            }
            // if idx not equals to k return old cell item
            return c;
          }),
        };
    
      }
     // if index is not equal i return old row item
      return item;
    });
    localTable.rows = updatedRows;
    setTable(localTable);
  }
```

I suppose `i` and `k` index values for the zero based array.

You can use `Object.reduce` method to calculate updated table object in your `changeCell` function; but personally I try to avoid from this because in general `Object.reduce` is less performant.